# How Download PDF selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I did put that configuration on  Chrome

```
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", @"C:\Downloads");
        Driver.driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

The PDF is opening in the browser in other tab, I don't have button to download.

I'm not able to clic on the element by id.

```
        ActionsSU.moveElementToClick(By.XPath("/html/body"));
        ActionsSU.moveElementToClick(By.Id("download"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the solution.

```
        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", @"C:\Downloads");
        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.directory_upgrade", true);
        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
```